# QStringList to QList<QStandardItem *>

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qstringlist

I have a list in QStringList with some items like this:

```
("name0", "name1", "name2",...)
```

that I need to pass to a QTableView using:

```
appendRow(const QList<QStandardItem *> &)
```

so how can I get QList from QStringList to add items to my table?

Answer (score 1):

With `QTableView` you have to use a model. Usually this is done by subclassing `QAbstractTableModel`. More on the different Qt models here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html

> If you just want to display a simple table i suggest using `QTableWidget`.  The API works like this:

```
QStringList list = QStringList() << "name0" << "name1" << "name2";

ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(list.size());
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1, i,
            new QTableWidgetItem(list.at(i)));
```

> for adding data in columns and adding labels i would suggest this code:

```
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"List1", "List2"});

QStringList list1 = QStringList() << "name0" << "name1" << "name2";
QStringList list2 = QStringList() << "surname0" << "surname1" << "surname2" << "surname3";

addColumn(list1);
addColumn(list2);
```

function for adding columns:

```
void MainWindow::addColumn(const QStringList &list)
{
    // resize rowcount as needed. qMax needs #include <QtMath>
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(qMax(list.size(), ui->tableWidget->rowCount()));

    ui->tableWidget->insertColumn(ui->tableWidget->columnCount());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, ui->tableWidget->columnCount() - 1, new QTableWidgetItem(list.at(i)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I have few questions. First of all, this is the code I used to display data in rows instead of columns:
```
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(list1.size());
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"List1","List2"});
ui->tableWidget->insertColumn(ui->tableWidget->columnCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); ++i)
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->columnCount() - 1, i, new QTableWidgetItem(list1.at(i)));
```

Comment: So, setHorizontalHeaderLabels is not working, there is only number 1 in the first cell of the first row. And what about if I want to add another list, do I follow the same code but for a different QStringList or can I add that somehow here?
EDIT: setHorizontalHeaderLabels is working when I put it in the last line

Comment: Glad to help! :) I added some more code to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel({"a","b","c"});
QListView view;
view.setModel(model);
```

You don't need to use a QStandardItemModel for this case and it can just be a QListView.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Did you mean to use a `QStringListModel`?

Comment: I thought there was a an overloaded function for that.